# While loop never stops when I enter a character in a place

Tags: c

I have a problem with this loop when I enter a character for ˋscanfˋ. The loop will never stop. But when I enter a number all works good.

This Is The Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    int x;

    printf("Enter 1 Or 2\n");
    scanf("%i",&x);

    while (x!=1 && x!=2) {

        printf("Please Enter A Right Value \n");
        scanf("%i",&x);
    }

    printf("Finish");
}
```

Comment: @TusharWalzade No, he wants it to repeat until you enter a valid input.

Comment: A `do-while` would have been better here.

Comment: Have you understood it? I have explained it and check the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well when you input character, `scanf` actually tries to get those wrong character inputs from the `stdin` but as it is not as per the conversion specification provided it fails. And then it keeps those wrong input in the stdin. And next time the `scanf` fails again due to those wrong inputs. So you need to clear it before you attempt to get the input again using `scanf`. Also check the return value of `scanf` and in case it failed clear the `stdin`.

The provided code checks for `EOF` and also return value of `scanf` the standard says explicitly about the return value of `scanf` :-

**[7.21.6.2p16](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2p16)**

> The `fscanf` function returns ***the value of the macro `EOF` if an
>   input failure occurs before the first conversion (if any) has
>   completed***. Otherwise, the function *returns the number of input
>   items assigned*, which can be fewer than provided for, or ***even
>   zero, in the event of an early matching failure***.

The code will be something like **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48012277/validation-check-with-scanf-does-not-work-inside-a-loop/48012671#48012671)**. (This is using `scanf`).

Better even use `fgets`. you can easily and more better way control the erro neous inputs. With `fgets` you will read the entire line and then parse the integer input from it using `strtol` or `strtoul`. Yes in case of integer input there will be a case there also - you need to check if the parsed long or unsigned long is of proper size so that they can be kept in `int` variable.

Comment: Thanks, More Explication Please Im beginner In c

Comment: @Ron.: I see..but this is clearly understandable...I wil try to explain more clearly.